# How to map over json array in react native?

Tags: json, dictionary, react-native

hello everyone i want to render the json response returned from server for that i'm using map method. But there is a mistake in my code please help me to figure it..The response i'm getting is

response.json

```
{
status: true
token:{
 access_token: "BhTErqRtliUG#8"
 client_id: "ck4fLr08YHkW2y"
 expires: "2018-02-19 03:51:50"
 scope: null
 user_id:465
},
user:{
 avatar: "https://www.indianeconomy.net/lms/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/favicon.png"
 email: "tet@wehubs.afs"
 id:465
 name: "testere"
 sub:""
}
}
```

I've tried this

```
fetch(''{
.... }).then((responseData)=>{
this.setState({
        userdetail: responseData,
        loaded:true,
        })
}
render(){
return this.state.userdetail.map(user=>{
<Text>{token.access_token}</Text>
})
}
```

How to use map method over above json response?

Comment: You cannot loop over the object using `map` since you're getting an object from the response, not an `array`.

Comment: Also, the `object` is invalid in format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other comments are correct. You cannot map over an object like this. There are ways you can iterate over object properties:

```
for(let prop in object) {
  console.log(object[prop]);
}
```

However, in your example the objects don't have any similarities so you would not get any benefit from iterating over them.

If instead, you wanted to display the access token, you would do the following:

```
return (
   <Text>{this.state.userdetail.token.access_token}</Text>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

json string shown by you is not a valid json you can validate here https://jsonlint.com/

i am not sure about react but you mention dict so in python if you have valid json

you can map it with dict like this

```
json.loads(json_string)
```